# Python IP output (print) is not working correctly

Tags: python

I'm new in Python. Can't make my first script to work well. 
What I want:

1. get IP from xls
2. print that IP
3. telnet to IP
4. authorize
5. show run \n, exit \n
6. write output to file named "IP"
7. get next IP from xls

This XLS contains about 6k hosts. I've got some ideas about making multi-threading but know nothing about this yet. Will try soon.

Problem is, I can't get good "print(host)" output in console. Script work well, but instead of correct name of IP I see everytime first IP.

IP list:

10.1.115.105
10.1.115.108
10.1.115.143
etc.

I see in chat

[root@localhost python]# python3.3 telnet_bck.py

10.1.115.105

10.1.115.105

10.1.115.105

But the files are saving correctly

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16536 Apr  8 07:38 10.1.115.105

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16536 Apr  8 07:38 10.1.115.108

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16536 Apr  8 06:53 10.1.115.243

I guess problem is somewhere near "host = ip_addr_list[0]" but can't understand where. Please help, guys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import xlrd                     #Excel module
import re                       #Parser module
import os                       
import glob                     
import sys                      
import telnetlib                #telnet module
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('/samba/allaccess/test.xlsx')
sheet = rb.sheet_by_name('IPs')
num_rows = sheet.nrows
num_cols = sheet.ncols
ip_addr_list = [sheet.row_values(rawnum)[0] for rawnum in range(sheet.nrows)]
num_ips = 0
while num_ips < num_rows:
    host = ip_addr_list[0]
    port = "23"
    user = "test"
    password = "test"
    print(host)
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host,port)
    tn.read_until(b"ser name:")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii')+b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b"assword:")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii')+b"\n")
    tn.write(b"sh ru"+b"\n")
    tn.write(b"exit"+b"\n")
    str_all = tn.read_all()
    re.sub("^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$", '', str_all.decode())
    file = open('{0}'.format(ip_addr_list[num_ips]),"wb")
    file.write(str_all)
    num_ips += 1
```

Comment: you are printing `ip_addr_list[0]` but creating `ip_addr_list[num_ips]` filename.

Comment: thank you. trouble really was here. Is it possible to +rep comments, not answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly assume, problem is exactly in `host = ip_addr_list[0]`. `ip_addr_list` is list (array) of elements and `[0]` is index of element in list. So no matter how many times your loop runs, `host` will be always first element of your `ip_addr_list`.
In addition, there is more "pythonic" way of iterating over list. It would be:

```
for host in ip_addr_list:
    port = "23"
    user = "test"
    password = "test"
    print(host)
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host,port)
    tn.read_until(b"ser name:")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii')+b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b"assword:")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii')+b"\n")
    tn.write(b"sh ru"+b"\n")
    tn.write(b"exit"+b"\n")
    str_all = tn.read_all()
    re.sub("^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$", '', str_all.decode())
    file = open('{0}'.format(host),"wb")
    file.write(str_all)
    num_ips += 1
```

This way in every iteration of loop, your `host` will contain next element from `ip_addr_list`.
Also you may consider moving `port, user` and `password` definition out of the loop. They are always the same so theres no need to asigne then every time sa value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. By the way, what means "more "pythonic"" way? Why for xx in yy usage is better then "while"? I've found while in main manuals in official site

Comment: Short answer would be that "for xx in yy" loop takes care of iterating over each element in list. you don't have to worry about increasing index variable. Also, current element of the list ends up directly in "xx" variable and you dont have to reference it as "some_list[index]".
If you care about broader explenation you can read up here http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html